# Flutter GoRouter: Unable to Access Path Parameters Data, Receiving Null

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I'm facing an issue while passing data received from an API in my Flutter app. The data is retrieved in the `summarize_controller` and needs to be stored in multiple `TextEditingController` instances before being passed to another screen called `note_screen`. When I manually set data in the `TextEditingController` instances, everything works fine. However, when I try to pass the API data, it shows null, even though I can confirm that the API call is returning valid data.

This is how I have defined the route for my `note_screen`:

```
GoRoute(
  path: '/note/:title/:tags/:summary',
  name: 'note',
  builder: (context, state) {
    var pathParams = state.pathParameters;
    print("After passing: $pathParams");
    var title = pathParams['title'];
    var tags = pathParams['tags'];
    var summary = pathParams['summary'];
    return SafeArea(
      child: NoteScreen(
        title: title!,
        tagString: tags!,
        summary: summary!,
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

The code for the `summarize_controller` where I'm passing the data:

```
Future<void> generateSummarizedNote(BuildContext context, String inputText) async {
  var inputString = _escapeString(inputText);

  var jsonString = '''
  {
    "text": "$inputString"
  }
  ''';

  // titleController.text = "Hello";
  // tagsController.text = "tag1,tag2";
  // summaryController.text = "Hello is summary";

  var userData = jsonDecode(jsonString);
  var response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('${TextStrings.baseURL}/openai/summarize'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(userData),
  );

  var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
  titleController.text = responseBody['title'];
  tagsController.text = (responseBody['tags'] as List<dynamic>).join(', ');
  summaryController.text = responseBody['summary'];

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Title of note: ${titleController.text}");
    print("Tags of note: ${tagsController.text}");
    print("Summary of note: ${summaryController.text}");
    GoRouter.of(context).goNamed('note', pathParameters: {
      'title': titleController.text,
      'tags': tagsController.text,
      'summary': summaryController.text,
    });
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to summarize');
  }
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Finally, the redirection code I'm using to navigate to `note_screen`:

```
else if (isGoingToNote && auth) {
  print("State: ${state.pathParameters}");
  var title = state.pathParameters['title'];
  var tags = state.pathParameters['tags'];
  var summary = state.pathParameters['summary'];
  return '/note/$title/$tags/$summary';
}
```

When I use hardcoded values, everything works fine, but when I use data received from the API, it shows null. I'm not sure why this is happening, as the API call seems to be returning valid data.

Can someone please help me understand why the API data is not being passed correctly to the `note_screen` and how to resolve this issue?

[image: output image]

I was expecting to get the generated output in another screen, but got null.